# convert natural language to OCL script

Tags: eclipse, constraints, ocl, nlp

i have some statements in natural language that i have to convert to OCL format, i am beginner and  have written some by myself but failed to convert some advanced level statements , i have searched a lot like [this](https://modeling-languages.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/OCLChapter.pdf), [this](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-30982-3_3) and [this](http://download.eclipse.org/ocl/doc/5.0.0/ocl.pdf)  but failed to found something exact or similar.

statements that i want to convert:

1.Disable web server directory listing and ensure file meta data (e.g GIT) and backup files are not present within web roots

2.Log access failures , alert admins on repeated failures

3.Limit API and control access to minimize the harm from automated attack

4. Block SQL injection through query parameterization.

please help me

thanks

Comment: Eclipse is a development environment, **not** a programming language. Which of the many languages supported by Eclipse are you asking about?

Comment: actually i use eclipse for UML modeling with paypurus plugin... i need help to convert the above statements to OCL format , not the exact but some how OCL code express the technique. thanks

Comment: Your question is a hotchpotch of concepts, that may make sense to you but certainly not to me. Perhaps if you provided a concrete example of what you actually want to translate into what things might become clearer.

Comment: for example i have to write OCL constraint for this mitigation  technique :

"Log access failures , alert admins on repeated failures"

it means whenever  an illegal login attempt occurred on my system that fails then the system should log this failure in a file (may be .txt) and alert system admin.  that's is 

i think i have cleared now... please let me know if i missed something
thanks

Comment: Still not clear. If you have some tool that sends you the text "Log access failures , alert admins on repeated failures", you might use UML to model that as an input message, and then again use UML to model this with an output message 'Houston, we have a problem', which could be an OCL string, but I'm sure that's not what you want. Given that the foregoing could be an answer to what you have asked, maybe you can now ask something intelligible.

Comment: @EdWillink let's make it simple , is there any OCL constraint to mitigate an attack like SQL injection on a system ??? forget any other statements. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Natural language is imprecise and so cannot always be converted to a precise form such as OCL without additional human insight. The converse is possible.

The statements you want to convert appear to be from disciplined fields. You therefore just need to transliterate each idiom.

Comment: wilink thanks for your response. i was waiting for you actually i don't want each statement to be converted as same, some how similar scenario also acceptable that express the desired mitigation technique.